# mySQL view for two different tables?

Tags: mysql, view

I've a massive problem creating a view in mySQL:

Table A in database DB1:

```
CREATE TABLE `a` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'internal ID',
    `account` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `filename` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `filesize` BIGINT(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Table B in database DB2:

```
CREATE TABLE `b` (
        `archive_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `archive_datetime` DATETIME,
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `account` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `filename` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `filesize` BIGINT(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
    PRIMARY KEY (`archive_id`)
)
ENGINE=Archive
```

Entries from table A are automatically transfered to table B via trigger if BEFORE DELETE.

I need a view that gives me all entries from table a and table b as if they were still in one table of the same database. Columns `archive_id` and `archive_datetime` can be ignored in the view as they are not needed for this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `UNION`:

```
SELECT * FROM a UNION SELECT * FROM b;
```

You just have to replace `*` with the desired table columns.

Comment: That perfectly did the trick! UNION did not come into my mind :( Is there any way to include a column containing the table name where the corresponding entry is from?

Comment: You could adjust the query like `SELECT *, 'a' AS table_name FROM a UNION SELECT *, 'b' AS table_name FROM b;`. Again, just replace `*` with other desired table columns.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, account, filename, filesize FROM a UNION ALL SELECT id, account, filename, filesize FROM b
```

Surely I must be missing something?